# How can I make this custom bootstrap navbar responsive to viewport size?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following navbar, which works pretty well with my screen (1300 pixels wide by 700 high):

[image: Functioning navbar at my viewport's maximum size]

When the viewport is smaller, the elements in the navbar go crazy:

[image: Navbar at smaller viewport size]

I've found that switching between any of the typical bootstrap classes just cause more problems with alignment and sizing.

I tried to use this media query in my CSS but it did nothing at all:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .navbar .app-badge {
        display: block !important;
    }

}
```

I've tried a bunch of ways to adjust the bootstrap classes or use a media query. Nothing works. I need help figuring out how to make the navbar collapse on smaller viewports.

Here's my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-spur
    {% if not current_user.admin %}navbar-spur-user {% else %} navbar-spur-admin {% endif %}">
    <div class="border rounded border-1 border-white pt-1 pl-1 even-height ml-n1 app-badge">
        <a class="navbar-nav mr-auto text-center p-1" href="https://www.spur.community/holiday-cheer-drive">
            <div class="text-center ml-n1 mt-n1">
                <div class="stacked">
                    <img src="/static/logos/logo-spur-main.png">
                </div>
                <div class="stacked">
                    <span class="text-spur-ribbon m-1"><small><b>SPUR</b></small></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="border rounded border-1 border-white pt-1 pl-1 ml-3 even-height app-badge">
        <a class="navbar-brand p-0" href="/" title="Home">
            <div class="parallel">
                <img src="/static/logos/logo-spur-white.png">
            </div>
            <div class="parallel">
                <span class="text-spur-red">
                    <h1>
                        <em>
                            <b>SPUR</b>
                        </em>
                    </h1>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ml-1 parallel">
                <div class="mt-n2 stacked">
                    <small><span class="text-spur-green"><em>Holiday</em></span></small>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-n3 stacked">
                    <small><span class="text-spur-green"><em>Cheer</em></span></small>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-n3 stacked">
                    <small><span class="text-spur-green"><em>Drive</em></span></small>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% if current_user.admin %}
            <div class="mt-2 parallel">
                <span class="text-spur-ribbon mt-2 ml-2"><em>Admin</em></span>
            </div>
                {% endif %}
        </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <div class="navbar-nav border rounded border-1 border-white ml-3 pt-2 pb-2 even-height app-badge">
            {% for url, route, label in nav_main %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link {{ 'active' if active_page==route }}" href="{{ url }}">{{ label }}</a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% if current_user.admin %}
        <div class="navbar-nav border rounded border-1 border-white ml-3 pt-2 pb-2 even-height app-badge">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle {{ 'active' if active_page in admin_labels }}" data-toggle="dropdown"
                    href="" id="adminDropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Admin</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="adminDropdown">
                    {% for url, route, label in nav_admin_dropdown_top %}
                    <li><a href="{{ url }}"" class=" dropdown-item">{{ label }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    {% for url, route, label in nav_admin_dropdown_bottom %}
                    <li><a href="{{ url }}"" class=" dropdown-item">{{ label }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if current_user.is_authenticated and nav_logged_in %}
        <div class="navbar-nav border rounded border-1 border-white ml-3 pt-2 pb-2 even-height app-badge">
            {% for url, route, label in nav_logged_in %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link {{ 'active' if active_page==route }}" href="{{ url }}">{{ label }}</a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>


    <ul class="navbar-nav m1-auto">
        {% if current_user.is_anonymous %}
        <!-- e.g., if NOT current_user.is_authenticated -->

        <div class="navbar-nav border rounded border-1 border-white ml-3 pt-2 pb-2 even-height app-badge">
            {% for url, route, label in nav_anon %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link {{ 'active' if active_page==route }}" href="{{ url }}">{{ label }}</a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        {% elif current_user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if nav_right %}
        <div class="navbar-nav border rounded border-1 border-white ml-3 pt-2 pb-2 even-height app-badge">
            {% for url, route, label in nav_right %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link {{ 'active' if active_page==route }}" href="{{ url }}">{{ label }}</a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="navbar-nav border rounded border-1 border-white ml-3 pt-2 pb-2 even-height app-badge">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('user.logout') }}">Log Out</a>
            </li>
        </div>

        {% endif %}
    </ul>

</nav>
```

And my CSS (if you noticed the navbar-spur-admin class, it's the same as navbar-spur-user but with different colors):

```
/* NAVBAR */

/* NAVBAR */

/* NAVBAR */

/* BASE NAVBAR */

.navbar-spur, .navbar-spur .navbar-brand .navbar-nav {
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.navbar-spur .navbar-brand .parallel img {
    max-width: 2.5em;
}

.navbar-spur div a img {
    max-width: 1.5em;
}

.navbar-spur .even-height {
    height: 3.7em;
}

.navbar-spur .navbar-brand small {
    font-size: 0.7em;
}

.navbar-spur a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-spur .navbar-brand .parallel, .navbar-spur .navbar-nav .parallel {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar-spur .navbar-brand .stacked, .navbar-spur .navbar-nav .stacked {
    display: block;
}

/* USER NAVBAR */

.navbar-spur-user, .navbar-spur-user .navbar-brand .navbar-nav {
    background-color: #003274 !important;
}

.navbar-spur-user .app-badge {
    background-color: #002658 !important;
}

.navbar-spur-user .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    color: #356275 !important;
}

.navbar-spur-user .navbar-nav .nav-item .active {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Any advice, links to resources that would help me, or feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you can provide link to a reduced test case on codepen/jsfiddle that would make it easier to diagnose. It's also unclear how you actually want it to look on small viewports.

Your issue is likely something being set by the Bootstrap navbar styling classes and you should consult their documentation to understand what they do. Could be down to the use of `navbar-expand-sm`, maybe try a different breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Peter, I believe your problem has to do with the width of your logo under the class "navbar-brand". I had a similar issue, but fixed it by controlling the width of my logo under the Navbar-brand. According to bootstrap, "Adding images to the .navbar-brand will likely always require custom styles or utilities to properly size." Below is bootstraps example:

```
<!-- Just an image -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="/docs/4.4/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
  </a>
</nav>
```

Notice the width and height settings after the image. In my case I was able to change the width of my logo image in CSS within my media query for small screen sizes.